# Automatic text area resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have a text area that resizes automatically but now it ignores my css for the height of the text area and I can't find a way around it. It doesn't ignore any other css just the height attribute.

HTML

```
   <textarea id="test" class="text2" name="lgyesterday" onkeyup="resizeTextarea('test');" data-resizable="true"> </textarea>
```

CSS

```
.text2{
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    width:47%;
    font-family:sans-serif, "arial helvetica";
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 80px;
}
```

I just wondered if anyone had any idea how I could set the height of the textarea to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this:

```
onkeyup="resizeTextarea('test');"
```

That is most likely what is resizing the area using inline styles, that will override your CSS. You can also override the inline styles by adding `!important`:

```
height: 80px!important;
```

**EDIT**

Try the `min-height` if you want to prevent if from becoming lower:

```
min-height: 80px;
```

Comment: But then my text area wont automatically resize?

Comment: You want it to resize or you want the `height:80px` to be applied? Because you can’t have both :)

Comment: I need a default starting size that can then get bigger from there

Comment: Okey then, you probably should have mentioned that... anyway, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry I thought I'd been clear in my explanation no worries, Cheers dude min-height was spot on worked a treat, I'll make it the approved answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

The height attribute in your example works fine for me (Chrome). But it is also possible to define the height with the "rows" attribute. Example:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="10">
```

Comment: The height also works fine with me its just when the javascript is applied to it, it's overridden. The answer below worked a treat. Cheers anyway @Roland